# Symfony UX Swup, Unknown "stimulus_controller" function

Tags: symfony, symfony6, swup, symfonyux

I'm using symfony 6.3 and I have installed s**ymfony/ux-swup**:

```
//bundles.php
<?php

return [
   // ..............

    Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\UX\Swup\SwupBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\UX\Dropzone\DropzoneBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

I have followed the doc https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-swup/current/index.html#usage

The twig page

```
    <div {{ stimulus_controller('symfony/ux-swup/swup') }} id="swup" data-turbo="false">

    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">

         my content
       </div>
    </section>
   </div>
```

But I gor this twig function error:

> Unknown "stimulus_controller" function.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now it's in a separate bundle :

```bash
composer require symfony/stimulus-bundle
```